# Angular - how to use data from subcribe or map and set in object after post request

Tags: angular

After post request, this return me some data and I don't know how I can use this data and set to object class, or any object, or just print in console log.
Console log always write undefined object.

```js
onSubmit() 
  {
    this.http.post('some/api',
    JSON.stringify({
      user_name: this.login_form.value.user_name,
      password: this.login_form.value.password
    }),
    this.options
    )
    .subscribe(data =>  {
      this.getUserData = data[0];
      
      this.user = {
        Ime: data['Ime'],
        Prezime: data['Prezime'],
        Username: data['Username'],
        Sifra: data['Sifra'],
        Broj_telefona: data['Broj_telefona'],
        jmbg: data['jmbg'],
        Nivo: data['Nivo']
      }

    });

    console.log(this.user);
    console.log(this.getUserData);
  }

this is class User

export class User {
constructor(
    Ime: any,
    Prezime: any,
    Username: any,
    Sifra: any,
    Broj_telefona: any,
    jmbg: any,
    Nivo: any
) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.log` inside the subscribe block like this -

```
onSubmit() 
  {
    this.http.post('some/api',
    JSON.stringify({
      user_name: this.login_form.value.user_name,
      password: this.login_form.value.password
    }),
    this.options
    )
    .subscribe(data =>  {
      this.getUserData = data[0];

      this.user = {
        Ime: data['Ime'],
        Prezime: data['Prezime'],
        Username: data['Username'],
        Sifra: data['Sifra'],
        Broj_telefona: data['Broj_telefona'],
        jmbg: data['jmbg'],
        Nivo: data['Nivo']
      }
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log(this.getUserData);
    });
  }
```

As you are using `http` method which is asynchronous but `console.log` is running before this call.

Comment: Yes, this work but I must use this data and set to cookie or local storage.

Comment: Yes , so you need to set it to localstorage into subscribe block itself

Comment: Thats is problem. I fix it.
Thanks.